# Discord.py, Required argument that is missing

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
from discord.utils import get
import discord


TOKEN = '########' #Taken out
BOT_PREFIX = '!'
ROLE = 'Bot'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as: " + bot.user.name + "\n")


@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role("Sergeant") # This must be exactly the name of the appropriate role
async def addrole(ctx, members):
    member = ctx.message.author
    role = get(member.server.roles, name="Test")
    await bot.add_roles(member, role)


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

So the code above is what I use.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 790, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 751, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 670, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\Joshua\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 516, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: author is a required argument that is missing.
```

And this is the error, I belive this is todo with the rewrite but honestly I can't get to grips with it. If anyboby could shine some light on this I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so first you need to import commands from discord at the top of your file. Your bot variable calls this when grabbing the prefix:

```
from discord.ext import commands
```

Next, you no longer need `pass_content=True` in `@bot.command()`, as context is now always passed. The documentation stating that can be found [here.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#context-changes)

I noticed that you are checking if the author has a role by name. Although this does work, a better method is checking if the author has the permissions to manage roles, or if he/she is an administrator. That is typed like so:

```
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
```

A full list of the different arguments that you can pass into that decorator are found [here.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions.create_instant_invite)

Now regarding your error message, you have a parameter called members in your command function. Since this is a positional parameter, you must provide it when typing your command in discord. However, its not doing anything in your code, so you can remove it:

```
async def addrole(ctx):
```

More info on command parameters can be found [here.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#parameters)

In you variable named member, you can change `ctx.message.author` to `ctx.author`.

In the role variable, when attempting to get the roles on your server, we no longer use `member.server.roles`. It has been changed to `guild`, as shown in the [docs.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#server-is-now-guild) Here's how you would type it:

```
role = get(member.guild.roles, name="Test")
```

And the final change is adding the role to the member. The rewrite version of discord.py removed a lot of functionality from `bot`. The `add_roles` function is now called from a member object, so this would be written like so:

```
await member.add_roles(role)
```

We're taking your member variable (ctx.author, which is a member object) and adding a role (the role variable, which fetches a role object with the name Test) to that member. Docs on it are found [here.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#models-are-stateful)

So your code should look something like this:

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import discord


TOKEN = '########'  # Taken out
BOT_PREFIX = '!'
ROLE = 'Bot'

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as: {bot.user.name}")


@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def addrole(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    role = get(member.guild.roles, name="Test")
    await member.add_roles(role)


bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I hope this helps with your problem :-)
Here's some links that can help you get a better grip on how discord.py-rewrite works:

[Migrating to the rewrite branch](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#migrating-to-v1-0)

[Discord.py Rewrite API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply I read through what you sent and I tried it. Unfortently I got an error

Comment: raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: Do you have other code in your file? Without a line to the error, I can't help out much, since id isn't being called anywhere in the snippet of code I provided.